# Clearing content of a datagrid cell based on DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkd or unchecked

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with 2 cells. one is DataGridCheckBoxColumn and other is DataGridTextColumn. when DataGridCheckBoxColumn is unchecked i want to clear content of the DataGridTextColumn.the data is comming from database but user can edit it .please tell me how to do this

```
<DataGrid Name="--" ItemsSource="{Binding Saukhtemauns}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="--"   Binding="{BindingShenaseDarad}">                                                                
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

    <DataGridTextColumn Header="--"  Binding="{Binding IDTakhribi}"/>                                                                                                                                
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: do you have viewmodels? please show some code, how are you assigning datasource to datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

If the class that you are assigning as a source to DataGrid implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you can do this easily on view model side

Inside bool property change set text property to empty

```
public string StrPropertyThatBindedToGridColumn
{
   get{return _strProp;}
   set{_strProp = value; OnPropertyChanged("StrPropertyThatBindedToGridColumn");}
}

public bool BoolPropertyThatBindedToGridColumn
{
   get{return _bProp;}
   set{
        _bProp = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("BoolPropertyThatBindedToGridColumn");
        if(value)
            StrPropertyThatBindedToGridColumn = null;
   }
}
```

If you handle INotifyPropertyChanged correctly, grid will follow the changes and will update UI

Comment: I'm using linq to sql. this datagrid datacontext is connected to an Entity class

Comment: it is not good practice to show linq to sql generated classes directly in UI, it should be wrapped in viewmodel, however as a workaround you can create partial class with custom boolean property, bind this one to grid instead of first one, and in set of this property set text as empty. as I remember linq generates INotifyPropertyChanged, so it should be enough